# How to decrypt bet365 socket data

Tags: sockets, websocket, live

I connected to the bet365 socket to get the data but how do I decrypt it or find the encryption method. For example, I need to know football ratings.

Example encryption provided below:

```
OV156735C19A_1_3U|LM=35;|OV15779175C78A_1_3U|LM=41;|OV202497715405430812C4A_1_3U|LM=3;|OV200234215405651012C91A_1_3U|LM=9;|EMPTYF|IN;EM=1;TO=5U6xva;|OV200234215405563902C91A_1_3U|SS=20-21;|OV78707673C18A_1_3U|TU=20190210152357;TS=18;|OV78893834C18A_1_3U|TU=20190210152357;TT=1;|OV78656106C18A_1_3U|LM=96;TU=20190210152356;TT=1;|OV78895473-2004688225_1_3U|SU=1;|OV78895473-2004688224_1_3U|SU=1;|OV78665222C18A_1_3U|LM=23;TU=20190210152357;TS=52;TT=0;|OV78665222C18-1446_1_3U|SU=1;|OV78707673C18A_1_3U|TS=17;|OV78859005C1A_1_3U|LM=10;|OV1531425C17A_1_3/OV1531425C17-170153_1_3I|MA;CN=2;FF=;FI=0;ID=170153;IT=OV1531425C17-170153_1_3;NA=Puck Line;OR=0;PC=OV_17_1_3;SU=0;SY=0;TO=;|OV78896148-2004774792_1_3U|HA=+6.5;HD= +6.5;OD=4/5;|OV78896148-2004774791_1_3U|HA=-6.5;HD= -6.5;OD=20/23;|OV78868338C18A_1_3U|TU=20190210152357;TS=9;|OV78888763C18A_1_3U|TU=20190210152357;TS=26;TT=0;|
```

Screenshot of encrypted data with readable fragments below:

[image: bet365 socket data]

Comment: That data is not encrypted

Comment: This is overview data. To catch the full event data click the event or match.
OV156735C19A_1_3U
**OV**: OverView, **U**: Update message

Answer (score 0):

You are getting live sockets... This means... Cool -_-

Btw, to parse the live match socket, you should subscribe first to retrieve the specific match data.
The bet365 socket will get started sending odds data for the market after you subscribe(click on the browser). As you will see the browser is sending some text to bet365 ws server, when you click the event. Yes, this is subscribing.

1. Subscribing.
2. Retrieve the initial odds data from the bet365 ws. (Flag will be 'F')
3. After initial data, they will be sending only delta updates. (Flag will be 'U')

This data is just raw data but NOT encrypted, the values are correct. **HA/HD: Handicap, OD: Odds, ...**

Bet365 is using the secret key to encrypt only prematch odds value.
If you wanna know how to decrypt and ...

And I know you are stuck on getting a handshake on the live socket and ...

Comment: "Bet365 is using the secret key to encrypt only prematch odds value. If you wanna know how to decrypt and ..." - Hello Guys. I want to know about decrypttion... what should I do?

Comment: Would you mind to give some tips to decrypt pre match odds?